# Azure application Gateway Ingress controller

Tags: azure

I would want to know if the Azure Application Gateway ingress controller would allow connections based on TCP. I see that the Application Gateway Ingress Controller will support https in a lot of the publications. I would want to know if the Application Gateway Ingress Controller supports TCP-based load balancing or not ?

Application Gateway ingree controller will support TCP or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure application Gateway acts as a Level 7 load balancer and only supports http(s). That means that also Azure AGIC is a Level 7 load balancer. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview) for the different load balancers available.

Comment: After i read the document Application Gateway Ingress controller """AGIC helps eliminate the need to have another load balancer/public IP address in front of the AKS cluster and avoids multiple hops in your datapath before requests reach the AKS cluster. Application Gateway talks to pods using their private IP address directly and doesn't require NodePort or KubeProxy services. This capability also brings better performance to your deployments.""""https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview

Comment: Yes, but it does not support TCP.